What does buckets mean in prometheus?
I don't quiet understand what buckets mean in histogram function in prometheus
What does the bucket values means in
LATENCY = Histogram('hello_world_latency_seconds',
    'Time for a request Hello World.',
    buckets=[0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])

And
@LATENCY.time()

For example what bucket 0.0001 mean?

Buckets are properties of a Histogram.
When you look at a viszualized Histogram, its most likeley a bar-chart.
Every bar is a Bucket.
And the value of the Bucket (height of the Bar) is the count of numbers that fit into that bucket.
Fitting in a bucket means, a number is between either the last bucket value or 0 and the current bucket value.
So in your example it is:

Bucket 1: Values between [0 and 0.0001]
Bucket 2: Values between ]0.0001 and 0.0002]
Bucket 3: Values between ]0.0002 and 0.0005]
etc.

